# SQL 2005 - any way to restore/copy a diagram?

Tags: sql-server-2005, diagram, restore

I used the Redgate packager (ran MSI) to reset all the data in my database (i.e. I deleted everything, and let it build the new database).  Unfortunately, I discovered that it didn't retain my diagrams, which has a nice arrangement and several annotations.

Is there any way to copy/migrate/script the diagram from one database to another (the databases have identical structures).

Thanks,
Neal Walters

Answer (score 2):

You could try this using SQL2008 (may be different in SQL2005):

```
set IDENTITY_INSERT stackoverflow.dbo.sysdiagrams ON
--
insert into stackoverflow.dbo.sysdiagrams (name, principal_id, diagram_id, version, definition)
select name, principal_id, diagram_id, version, definition
 from dbo.sysdiagrams
--
set IDENTITY_INSERT stackoverflow.dbo.sysdiagrams OFF
```

Your target database will have the copied diagrams.